# Does javascript have a concept of negative zero

Tags: javascript, zero

Consider the following

```
var l = console.log.bind(console);
l(-0); // 0
l(0); // 0
l(0 === -0); // true
l(0 == -0); // true
l(1 / 0); // Infinity
l(1 / -0); // -Infinity
```

- Why is negative zero equal to zero ?
- Given it's equal why does it behave differently ?

**Bonus question:**

- Is the `0`/`-0` combination the only combination where equal objects behave differently?

I know `NaN`/`NaN` is a combination where non-equal objects behave the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is negative zero equal to zero ?

Because [IEEE 754 demands it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_zero#Comparisons).

> Is the `0`/`-0` combination the only combination where equal objects behave differently?

I believe so. In Javascript, only Numbers have a special `===` algorithm, and 0, -0, NaN are the only special cases there (ECMA-262 §11.9.6).

Comment: Where does it state ECMAScript implements the IEEE 754 ?

Comment: @Raynos: "§8.5 The Number Type". Ignoring IEEE 754, the two values are made equal in "§11.9.6 The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm" step 4.